# How to change UITextFields default border color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How can I set a default border color for UITextFields which are not in focus when the view appears? Tried this with no success:

```
class UITextFieldCustom : UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    init(frame: CGRect, size: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       }
```

Comment: Consider that the `init(coder` method is called if your cell is created from storyboard.

Comment: @vadian for storyboard the method to be used is `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 2):

If you can't see new border, try to increase its width:

```
layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that `self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor` is not called, because the function `init(frame: CGRect, size: CGFloat)` is not called. The reason why it is not called is because your textfield is not initilized in your code, for example:

```
func createTextField() -> UITextfield {
     return UITextfield(frame: .zero, size: 100.0)
}
```

Your textfield is initilized from the storyboard. That is why the other init function `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` exists. The sotryboard calls this function to initalize the textfield.

To solve the problem you just need to add your border modification line into the other init function, like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
```

Although one other clean approach I prefere more, is to add all setup code into the viewDidLoad method, for a clean overview, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextfield!
    
    // MARK: - View's Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTextfield()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup
    private func setupTextfield() {
        textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: In dark mode, the border remains black if it will not get the focus by force to be the first responder. Even If I set the  color within the viewDidLoad method. I want to see the border despite the text field has no focus. This seems only to work if the phone is in light mode? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

just place your code here as well, you probably don't call this from storyboard or nib.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use @IBDesignable class to create the border color and set the width, like this example.

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class BorderTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white{
        didSet{
                layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
}
```

the you can set the value in storyboard as needed.